# How to distinguish between a new feature and regression defect in Azure DevOps(VSTS) when filing a bug

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to understand how to distinguish between a new feature and regression bug when filing a defect. I do not see any fields that have this info. I can use the tags but it is very type prompted and not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom fields to an inherited process.  You could define a pool of valid values for the new field.  The steps for customizing the work item types is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

Answer (score 0):

There are different work item types. A "bug" is a defect. A "user story" or "product backlog item" is a new feature.